# convolution of two non-periodic, continuous and differentiable functions is a constant.

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I have the convolution of two non-periodic, continuous and differentiable functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is a constant $K \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e., $(f∗g)(t)=K \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can I conclude that $f$ or $g$ must be a constant? I need to mention that we  know $f$ has Fourier Transform but we do not know $g$ has Fourier Transform or not!

Comment: How do you know that the convolution is well defined?

Comment: Actually it is an equation I need to solve, resulting from KTC conditions.